# Handling the static variable across the class

Tags: java, android, memory-management, static-variables

In my android project I have stored all my Constant fields in one class, and that class has grown big(25+ integer, 30+ String, 3 hash Map, and few array of String) collection of static variable. I did this because i need to access these values in different classes(not all).

Is this going to consume a lot of memory? Should i go with it?

Comment: If you need them, you'll have to store them one way or another. Memory consumption depends on the actual size of your constant objects.

Comment: i dont think it should be a problem

Comment: even if i put these variable in different classes.....memory for static variable will be allocated(at the start of the program, in regular memory). So it will not make any difference.....will it?

Answer (score 2):

As @proflux told, For Storing constants you can use [Enums](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html).
1. When you need a **fixed set** of **constants**.
2. *enums* are **type safe**. With Strings all your items in all categories are the same type.
      There is nothing to stop you from feeding a fruit category to an animal parameter.
3. enums are **Comparable** and **Serializable** by default[`Java 5`]
4. Adding new **enum** constants, does not require *re-compilation* of the client code[`Java 5`]

You can find more information from [here](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/enum.html)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry much about the memory aspects, but from a maintainability standpoint those kinds of Constant classes can grow unwieldy over time.  You might want to see if any of your constant values are good candidate for [enums](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).